# Coffeescript and es6 in one project - migration in practise

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ecmascript-6

I have quite huge project (production bundle file is around 400kB) written in coffee script. And I have no idea how to plan migration to ES6. I know that there are tools like [Decaffeinate](https://github.com/eventualbuddha/decaffeinate) but I am not sure if it really works in bussiness practise.

I suppose that I can use ES6 and coffee in one project but is it possible to write components in coffee which import and use code written in ES6 and vice versa and all works in production?

Is this migration possible to be done step by step or there is no other option than doing everything in one release?

How does webpack work (proper loader)? What is the sequence? Does it firstly convert ES6 to JS (or coffee to JS) and then do all imports or import files first and then convert to JS?

Finally are there some best practices to have code written in both coffee script and ES6 in similar situation?

Comment: With Webpack you configure it to do what you want it to. It it definitely possible to have a product split between ES6 and Coffeescript. Out of curiosity, why are you doing this, though?

Comment: @maxple because I have huge project written in coffee and I want to migrate to es6. I have no idea how to do this painless

Answer (score 2):

I'm the main person working on decaffeinate recently. It has been used on large production codebases and currently has no known bugs, so it's likely stable enough for you to use it. Still, you should convert your codebase a small piece at a time rather than all at once.

You can configure webpack to allow both CoffeeScript and JavaScript in the same project by specifying coffee-loader for .coffee files and babel-loader for .js files in your `module.rules` (or `module.loaders` for webpack 1).

If you use `require` syntax, importing code between CoffeeScript and JavaScript should just work without any problems. If you use JS `import`/`export` syntax, you may need to use `require('./foo').default` in some cases when requiring JavaScript from within a CoffeeScript file. But in most cases interop should just work even with `import`/`export` syntax.

Probably a good idea is to convert one or two files and make sure eslint, babel, and other JavaScript config are configured they way you want them to. From there, you should convert the code one or two files at a time, and increase the number of files you convert at once as you get more comfortable with it and depending on what your needs are.

One approach is to convert CoffeeScript files to JS slowly over time, converting and cleaning up the ones you touch. The problem I've seen with this approach is that it can be a very long time before you move off of CoffeeScript. It depends on your situation, but generally I would recommend running decaffeinate in larger and larger batches without focusing too much on manual cleanup, then once the codebase is 100% JavaScript, manually clean up files as you work with them.

A while ago, I wrote up some thoughts on how to think about different conversion strategies, which you might find useful:
https://github.com/decaffeinate/decaffeinate/blob/master/docs/conversion-guide.md#converting-a-whole-project